# How to ask for CoreMotion permission again?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-motion

After adding "Privacy - Motion Usage Description" to the Info.plist

I ran it and it worked and even asked for permission on the first run and I denied the permission and now I'm stuck because I can't find out how to popup the permission alert again.

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.pedometer startPedometerUpdatesFromDate:[NSDate date] withHandler:^(CMPedometerData * _Nullable pedometerData, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        // this block is called for each live update
        [self updateSteps:pedometerData];
    }];
}

-(void) updateSteps:(CMPedometerData *)pedometerData{
    if ([CMPedometer isStepCountingAvailable]) {
        NSLog(@"Steps count:%@",[formatter stringFromNumber:pedometerData.numberOfSteps]);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Step Counter not available.");
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't get the system to display the dialog again (unless you remove the app from the device).   Once the user answers the question, they are never asked again; they can change it from the app settings

Comment: Thank you for your fast respond sir.

Comment: If the user accidently presses NO on permission popup, just guide the user to your application in phone settings, where user can toggle respective permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iOS, we can never show an authorization dialog again
However, we can show the user steps to change the permission from the s
Settings.